# Paypal site is not redirecting after successful payment in mobile browser

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Paypal site is redirecting after successful payment in desktop browser
**but not in mobile browser**

When I am making payment from mobile browser I am getting the following error

> [INFO: CONSOLE(2)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeClass' of
>   null", source:
>   https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/WEBSCR-640-20160131-1/Mobile/js/min/checkout.js
>   (2)

Comment: so what is the problem !??!?!?
you didn't define what is the problem and how we can help you and what you want to achieve

Comment: @Smartiz Paypal not redirecting to success return url after payment completion
in mobile browser.

Comment: did you test it with all browsers on your phone? does this problem happen just in one phone ?

Comment: @Smartiz i have tested on Chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

well, First-off you should elaborate your question with details and a proper link. I wont open anything that doesn't check through. Now coming back to your question. And, I'm basing my answer with whatever little information you provided, this question really isn't worth without proper information.[Refer this.](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/CB_Billing/M_Payment_Gateways/Supported_Payment_Gateways/PayPal_Payflow_Pro%2C_Website_Payments_Payflow_Edition%2C_Website_Pro_Payment_Gateway)

Just a few checks along the way, are you using similar browser on both devices. If not, mention that also, mention what browser in particular that'll be required too. Sometimes your security settings get in the way, check your sec settings on the respected device. Most obvious reason could be failure to complete packet data request in-time, your device took too long to respond to the request.You know why this happens right,[see this :)](https://github.com/owncloud/android/issues/516). Hence the service was denied. Simple!.